# Delete admin inlines on form data change

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have three inlines in my admin and I just want to delete one inline among them whenever a model field in header got changed.

I tried below code and its working fine but gets delete all the three inlines instead of desired one inline.

```
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
    formset.save()
    if 'total' in form.changed_data:
        for x in formset.forms:
            obj = x.instance
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.delete()
```